# Panel to the left of visual studio code gone

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I right-clicked on that panel where you see the extensions, search, docker, and git buttons on visual studio code and clicked on some options. I was just experimenting. Now it's gone, and I don't know how to get it back. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try View -> Appearance -> Show Activity bar

Comment: Phew. Thanks a lot!